# Cant find a 3rd party QWidget with injected code & QWidget::find(hwnd)

Tags: qt, dll, hook, code-injection, qwidget

I have a dll in a third party address space, hooked using a cbt hook.  However, when I try and do this:

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(wct_target_wnd);
    QWidget* widget = QWidget::find(hwnd);
    if(widget != 0) 
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"worked\n",NULL, NULL);
    }
```

I know the widget is there, the hwnd is correct, I just can't seem to get a pointer to it.

According to everything that I have read this should work but it always return zero, can anybody suggest why?

c++ visual-studio-2008

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about using QApplication, getting a list of all the widgets then checking their respective window ids?

Something like

```
foreach (QWidget *widget, QApplication::allWidgets())
{
     if(widget->winId() == hwnd)
     {
         MessageBox(NULL, L"worked\n",NULL, NULL);
     }
}
```

Comment: That seems like a good idea :)  I tried it but it came back empty.  I think it is the way that the project is set up.  I have my .dll has all the connections to the QtCore4 and QtGui4 dlls, and then this is pushed into the third party app.  I think they are each using their own versions of the dll's which is why I can't find them, does this sound even right? - totally new to qt.

Comment: @flavour404: That might well be the case. If you have two instances of the same DLLs, you'll also end up with e.g. two instances of each static variables, including the one for the QApplication.

Comment: Frank, actually how could I test this so that I can confirm that that is actually what is going wrong, so to speak?